# Removing custom sort order from admin page listing

Tags: php, pages, admin, sort

For the background to my question: On my page listing, I've got a set of pages that are countries and the child pages  of those are categorised into 'Types'. So I've got a page structure like this:

```
Country 1
-- Resource
-- Resource
-- Organisation
-- Overview

Country 2
-- Overview
-- Overview
-- Overview
-- Organisation

Country 3
.
.
.
```

I've added in some additional filters to display only child pages of a selected country and when this filter is in action, an additional column is shown to show what 'Type' the page is. I've also added the necessary code to make this column sortable. So my code is as follows:

```
// Add Type column
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'my_columns');
function my_columns($columns) {
    if(!empty($_GET['country']) && empty($_GET['type'])) {
        $column_type = array('type' => 'Type');
        $columns = array_slice($columns, 0, 2, true) + $column_type + array_slice($columns, 3, NULL, true);
    }
    return $columns;
}

// Populate Type column
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', 'my_show_columns');
function my_show_columns($name) {
    if(!empty($_GET['country']) && empty($_GET['type'])) {
        global $post;
        switch ($name) {
            case 'type':
                $type = get_field('type', $post->ID);
                echo $type;
        }
    }
}

// Make Type column sortable
add_filter('manage_edit-page_sortable_columns', 'my_website_manage_sortable_columns');
function my_website_manage_sortable_columns($sortable_columns) {
    if(!empty($_GET['country']) && empty($_GET['type'])) {
        $sortable_columns['type'] = 'type';
    }
    return $sortable_columns;
}

// Add sort logic
add_filter('request', 'type_column_orderby');
function type_column_orderby($vars) {
    if (isset($vars['orderby']) && 'type' == $vars['orderby']) {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
            'meta_key' => 'type',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value'
        ));
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

So I can sort the Type ASC or DESC fine, but how would I go about reverting to the default sorting of the page listing where it shows the indented hierarchy of the pages?

Comment: What order you want by default? Because your custom column is depended  on condition `!empty($_GET['country']` So when it is not set then it is good to list the pages in hierarchy! isn't it ?

Comment: When I filter by country then sort by type, I want to be able to go back to being listed in the hierarchy (as it is by default) if i remove the filter. That's what I'm unsure on how to achieve. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default pages are order by `menu_order` then `title`. 
When you are adding filter `country` you are ordering them by `meta_value`

There are two options

1. Remove everything that you added `country` and `orderby` pages will be back to default order.
2. If you can not remove `orderby` but can remove `country` then adjust your code in this way and order pages again by `menu_order title` only when country is not set and `orderby` is `type`.

Updated code:-

```
function type_column_orderby($vars) {
    // You can also wrap this code in one more condition using $vars to only alter page list!
    if (!empty($_GET['country']) && isset($vars['orderby']) && 'type' == $vars['orderby']) {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
            'meta_key' => 'type',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value'
        ));
    } else if (empty($_GET['country']) && isset($vars['orderby']) && 'type' == $vars['orderby']) {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
            'orderby' => 'menu_order title',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        ));
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

> NOTE: `request` filter effect every query so wrap your filter in
>   `load-edit.php` action to only alter the post type listing query.

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'custom_page_order' );
function custom_page_order() {
    add_filter('request', 'type_column_orderby');
}
```

Comment: Getting some weird behavior now - When I filter by country, sort by type and then remove the county filter (which is the point I want it to go back to the default listing), it's only bringing back exactly 100 rows and no pagination..

Comment: @LoboDemon Not sure why but you also need to set the `'posts_per_page' => -1` because default query has it. Updated my answer.

Comment: That's sorted it! Thanks so much. What was also weird, was that it wasn't  even the first 100 rows that were being returned..

Comment: Glad it works! Not sure why it behaves like that I will debug this and comment here! Good Luck :)